# How to resolve promise in if statement?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, resolve

I have an array of objects as: `{ id: '1582715', email: 'email@gmail.com', isUsed: false }`, and I have many documents in MongoDB with same keys.
Before writing new array of objects in BD, I want to check does objects of array already been written to DB.

I wrote this func that returns array of objects that hasn't been written yet:

```
const forWriting = testimonalsArray.filter(isWritten => {
    if (collection.countDocuments({ id: { $eq: isWritten.id } }) < 1) return isWritten
})
console.log(forWriting)
```

BUT `collection.countDocuments({ id: { $eq: isWritten.id } }` returns `Promise { <pending> }`. I've tried add `async` `await`:

```
const forWriting = testimonalsArray.filter(async isWritten => {
    if (await collection.countDocuments({ id: { $eq: isWritten.id } }) < 1) return isWritten
})
console.log(forWriting)
```

but still didn't receive any result. How should I resolve this promise to have an integer to compare it with 1?

Comment: You cannot expect `forWriting` to be the result, since that is assigned synchronously (now), and your answer will only be available asynchronously (in some future).

Comment: and what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Since the result can only become available in some future, you cannot expect that the assignment to `forWriting` will be the result you need, since that assignment happens *now*, while the result is only there in some *future*.

You can do it however in an asynchronously executed callback (in the future), using `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(testimonalsArray.map(isWritten => 
    collection.countDocuments({ id: { $eq: isWritten.id } })
)).then(counts => {
    const forWriting = counts.map((count, i) => count < 1 && testimonalsArray[i])
                             .filter(Boolean);
                             
    console.log(forWriting);
});
```

This assumes that `testimonalsArray` will not change while awaiting the counts to come back from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an async function and first await for `collection.countDocuments({ id: { $eq: isWritten.id } })`, and then use resolved value. Like this

```
(async () => {
   const dbRequest = await collection.countDocuments({ id: { $eq: isWritten.id } });
   const forWriting = testimonalsArray.filter(isWritten => {
      if (dbRequest < 1) return isWritten
   })
   console.log(forWriting)
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter all matching documents in the collection with this single query.  Here is a snippet to use in an async callback, more performant at the same time since it queries DB just a single time.

```
const testimonialsAlreadyInTheDB = await collection.find({
   id: { $in: testimonalsArray.map(({id}) => id)}
})

const forWriting = testimonialsArray.filter(({id}) => !testimonialsAlreadyInTheDB.find(id))
```